# Is there a way to restrict the HTML datetime-local picker to only show 15 minute intervals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the HTML input tag to show only 15 min intervals

```html
<div>
  <input type="datetime-local" step="900" />
</div>
```

The above (setting step) does not work.

I am writing in React. I would prefer not to use an external package or build my own datepicker as I want to use the browser's native implementation.

Comment: I think you're as close as you're going to get, the rest is up to the browser to implement.  Compliant providers of `datetime-local` will at least validate that the input matches the 15 minute interval.  Chrome e.g. will also step by 15 minutes when using the up/down keys in the minute field.  But whether they only show 00/15/30/45, or whether they show all minutes and just fail validation on others, is a UX decision made by the browser.  Which is the caveat of wanting to use the native implementation.